# node: converting buffers to decimal values

Tags: node.js, math

I have a buffer that is filled with data and begins with `< Buffer 52 49 ...>`

Assuming this buffer is defined as `buf`, if I run `buf.readInt16LE(0)` the following is returned:

> 18770

Now, the binary representation of hex values 52 and 49 are:

> 01010010 01001001

If I were to convert the first 15 bits to decimal, omitting the 16th bit for two's complement I would get the following:

> 21065

Why didn't my results give me the value of 18770?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

18770 is `01001001 01010010` which is your 2 bytes reversed, which is what the `readInt*LE` functions are going to do.

Use `readInt16BE`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this: `parseInt("0x" + buf.toString("hex"))`.  Probably a lot slower but would do in a pinch.